# Prevent interface merging from standard lib types

Tags: typescript, types

I have an interface called `Account` in my `types.d.ts` file:

```
interface Account {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

However, when I use it, I also get fields from `lib.dom.d.ts`:

```
{
    displayName: string;
    id: string;
    imageURL?: string;
    name?: string;
    rpDisplayName: string;
    contactRelations: ContactRelation[];
}
```

I know this is because I have `"lib": ["dom"]` in my `tsconfig.json`, but is there some way to prevent these types from being merged?

Renaming my domain interface is the obvious work around, but I'm just curious if there is a more elegant way to deal with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using [namespaces and modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) if you are introducing types whose names conflict with global types.  This would require that you reference these types via namespace or by `import`ing them in other files, so while this is arguably the "correct" way to do it, it's sort of a roundabout way of renaming your interface:

```
namespace MyNameSpace {
  export interface Account {
    id: string;
    name: string;
  }
}

const account: MyNameSpace.Account = { id: "", name: "" };
```

---

If you *need* your own global type named `Account`, there's also the option of renaming the conflicting interface from your local copy of the standard library.  For example you could edit [this line](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.8.3/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L25):

```
// Account --> AccountDOM
interface AccountDOM {
    displayName: string;
    id: string;
    imageURL?: string;
    name?: string;
    rpDisplayName: string;
}
```

and [this line](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.8.3/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L16512):

```
interface WebAuthentication {
    getAssertion(assertionChallenge: Int8Array | Int16Array | Int32Array | Uint8Array | Uint16Array | Uint32Array | Uint8ClampedArray | Float32Array | Float64Array | DataView | ArrayBuffer | null, options?: AssertionOptions): Promise<WebAuthnAssertion>;
    // Account --> AccountDOM
    makeCredential(accountInformation: AccountDOM, cryptoParameters: ScopedCredentialParameters[], attestationChallenge: Int8Array | Int16Array | Int32Array | Uint8Array | Uint16Array | Uint32Array | Uint8ClampedArray | Float32Array | Float64Array | DataView | ArrayBuffer | null, options?: ScopedCredentialOptions): Promise<ScopedCredentialInfo>;
}
```

This might not scale particularly well, especially since you'd need to keep merging this change in when you update your libraries, but standard libraries are standard, not inviolable; there are some types, like `Array` and `String` that are so baked into the language that you couldn't change them even in the library files.  But this `Account` type isn't one of them.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBZAngOXBAynRSA3gLABQSSEAHjAPYBOALkgJbCMT0BmCyAgvHi0AruyJkKFFgBMAXEiiN6bAOYBuCZNCR5i5cHWaAvmROkyQ4IqQIhoxvPRZIeXgDoBdsQF4irOUgARIEANEjaEPLBSEYa5vEA9EnJKQlk6aRJSJ4iYgC0eQB82YK5jAAiAPIoSGRsHNy8JV4V1eLkSNIssAA2IJjYukqqcVIBeiOaLGAgKhAAqgBKADIA-EP6hh0R6wrDBqNI9DDl3TB9Azp7m3FmdeycPAQA6hAARnzCjAAWEOws8BAjBYtGA7Qoc0YfCgUE4wNBAAoQDC4SDgABhb4gHo9P5zeQASXYAA4+PR6P0kAAfJBExgARgAbGSKWhqbT2ABmABMLMpNPm9VJ5P5SEF7CZfLZAvqPKl7PFjGJ6L6YBgEGk8ppADEerQgXKRdKkLr9YxGQAWLVIcpAkAANRYEAA7uypQAhYRcLicdnAYQ4sK0GDwqy7aGwphoyohtFQACU8gACvRaGBuhAADyvD5fb7ACOo0GFQ5ZHL2JAFYrl9hVFCaGYAawg6PoGr+wOxSNK9iJXAYM1D8hrrRQYXg9DQIdoSZAFMgDSg8hwQnV0lb7f+2Nn84gi4A2gBdMJAjiKIFozHY3EGSIcpXWumSo3sumG1kKoXWxXPj8yrm8i+-5Kiq4BrtapoGoBf4mnqQKWtatqMA6TqujSHpej69B+gGPRBrGoJQLsK7BhqG7SB2LDYjGoYJsmqbprCmYkWu5GUdifa0CWphAA)